# Expectation of product of two order statistics

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, expected-value, order-statistics

Let $X_1, X_2,\ldots, X_n$ be $n$ i.i.d. random variables with $f(x)$ as the pdf and $F(x)$ as the cdf in interval $[a,b]$. Let $X_{i:n}$ be the $i^\text{th}$ order statistic such that $X_{1:n}\leq X_{2:n}\leq \cdots \leq X_{n:n}$. How does one compute the expected value $E [X_{k:k} X_{i:n}]$ for any $k< i \leq n$ ($X_{k:k}$ is the highest order statistic if there are only $k$ i.i.d. random variables)? Also, are $X_{k:k}$ and $X_{i:n}$ independent?

Comment: Just to be clear, there are two different but identically distribute samples, so that $Y_{k:k}$ is the largest of $k$ and $X_{i:n}$ is the $i$-th of $n$, and you want to know $\mathbb{E}[Y_{k:k} X_{i:n}]$?

Comment: Not really. $X_{k:k}$ is identically distributed as $\frac {X_{k:n}}{X_{(k+1):n}}$ i.e. the ratio of $X_{k:n}$ and $X_{(k+1):n}$.

Comment: If they are from the same sample, $X_{k:n}$ gives you a lower bound on the support of $X_{i:n}$, $i>k$. The sequence of draws can be modelled as a Markov chain.  So it definitely matters if they are different samples or the same sample.  The fact that you are assuming $\mathbb{E}[X_{k:k} X_{i:n}] \neq \mathbb{E}[X_{k:k}]\mathbb{E}[ X_{i:n}] $ and there needs to be more analysis shows there's a problem with your question.  If they are different samples, they're independent; if they're not, the support of one depends on the realization of the other, but it can be integrated out.

Comment: I get what you are trying to say. The question was framed assuming that the samples are not different. I could as well frame the question as $E[ \frac {X_{k:n}}{X_{(k+1):n}} X_{i:n}] = ?$

Comment: If the samples are different, the realizations are independent and the expectation is just $\mathbb{E}[X_{k:k}] \mathbb{E}[X_{i:n}]$; if the realizations aren't independent, the realization of one impacts the support of the other.  It's not what "I am trying to say", it's the entire question.

Comment: How does one go about it if realization of one impacts the support of the other?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we're looking at the random variable $x_{k:n}x_{i:n}$, $i>k$, from the same sample.  The joint density is
\begin{multline}
f(x_{k:n},x_{i:n}) = \dfrac{n!}{(k-1)!(i-k-1)!(n-i)!}F(x_{k:n})^{k-1}\\
[F(x_{i:n})-F(x_{k:n})]^{i-k-1}[1-F(x_{i:n})]^{n-i}f(x_{i:n})f(x_{k:n})
\end{multline}
Then the expectation $\mathbb{E}[x_{k:n}x_{i:n}]$ can be computed as
$$
\int_{x_{k:n} = -\infty}^{\infty} \int_{x_{i:n} = x_{k:n}}^\infty x_{k:n}x_{i:n} f(x_{k:n},x_{i:n})dx_{i:n} dx_{k:n}.
$$

If the two variables are from two independent but identical samples, then 
\begin{multline}
\mathbb{E}[x_{k:n} x_{i:n}] = \mathbb{E}[x_{k:n}]\mathbb{E}[x_{i:n}] = \int_{\infty}^\infty z\dfrac{(n-1)!}{(n-1-k)!(k-1)!}F^{k-1}(z)[1-F(z)]^{n-k}f(z)dz \\
*\int_{\infty}^\infty z\dfrac{(n-1)!}{(n-1-i)!(i-1)!}F^{i-1}(z)[1-F(z)]^{n-i}f(z)dz.
\end{multline}

Comment: The first expression is the standard formula for joint pdf of two or more order statistics. But my question was about $X_{k:k}$ and not $X_{k:n}$. Will it hold for $X_{k:k}$ too?

Comment: In the standard order stat framework, you take $n$ draws and rank then, so their joint pdf is $n! f(x_{1:n}) f(x_{2:n})... f(x_{n:n})$ if $x_{1:n}<...<x_{n:n}$ and zero otherwise.  All the formulas are derived from that density.  You can't have $x_{k:k}$ and $x_{k:n}$ in the same "sample": that arrangement of symbols is not meaningful.

Comment: Thanks. Can I reframe my question? I actually want to find out $E[\frac {X_{k:n}}{X_{(k+1):n}} X_{i:n}]$ for $k +1 < i \leq n$.